# Awarding bounty when grace period has ended

Tags: support

According to SO, if OP has not awarded the bounty after all deadlines have expired, half its value will be automatically awarded to the highest ranking answer, provided that it has a score > 2.

In [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32104890/2567683) though I saw no automatic awarding so I wonder what happened.

Comment: Might just be a timing thing? Wait a few hours perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you're mistaken? "Yesterday" doesn't quite mean that the same here as it does in the rest of the world, it seems to mean "between 24 and 48 hours ago". OP posted answer on 6th (Sunday), bounty ended *actually yesterday* the 7th.

Comment: @TZHX: and looking again I see I mistook a 6 for a 7. Not sure how that happened. My mistake, OP is to get their +25 soon.

Comment: @MartijnPieters FWIW When I answered it wrote that I still have some hours left. I might be mistaken, there might be a bug involving multiple time zones

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: no, my mistake. You had almost 20 hours to spare.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The automatic awarding phase happens *some time* after the grace period ends. When exactly is not defined, usually within a few hours.

In other words, have a little patience, now that the grace period has ended the automatic awarding will happen soon enough. A batch script is run several times a day.

In this case, your answer qualifies for half the bounty; +25. It was posted some 20 hours before the bounty period ended, at 14:00 UTC yesterday, and all 3 upvotes arrived before the deadline too.